# SD mounting in my Sony Xperia L

Tags: server

I have recently bought a Sony Xperia l and when I insert my sd card it doesn't mount. Nothing shows that there is a memory card inserted, thus the files do not appear and yet in other phones the card shows.I don't know whether it's because the sd has a password. Please help :-/

Answer (score 0):

- First on your phone,go into `Settings-->Xperia-->connectivity-->Change the USB connection mode to Mass storage mode`.
- Now connect your phone with Ubuntu pc via data cable.Your `sdcard` will be mounted and you can see,transfer files.